# mySQL query returning Resource id #5

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've searched about possible solutions to this. and I've tried looping as well as trying the variants of mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array but I'm still getting the Resource id #5: 0: error.

Here's my code which I think generates the error.

```
   <?php
            mysqlc();
            $email = GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user'], "text");
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM newmember WHERE email = %s",$email);
            $res = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    ?>
```

Comment: Firstly, why is this tagged with Facebook tags? Secondly, there's no code here that prints anything out - what is the value of `$res`? What are you doing with `$row`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Resource id #5: 0" is not an error. It means that you tried to `echo $res` instead of trying to use the `$row` variable, such as $row[column] for fetch_assoc, $row[0] for fetch_row, either/both for fetch_array.

The other answers explain the use of mysql_fetch_*

Also, mysql_* is deprecated. You should use mysqli_* or PDO functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Please use this one :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){

              //do somthing 
              echo $row->name;

        }
```

I am already use this one in our code

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

```
<?php
 $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT id, email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$resultado) {
echo 'No se pudo ejecutar la consulta: ' . mysql_error();
 exit;
}
$fila = mysql_fetch_row($resultado);

echo $fila[0]; // 42
echo $fila[1]; // el valor de email
?>
```