# Get Resource id #5 instead of mySQL result

Tags: php

I've searched about possible solutions to this. And I've tried trying the variants of mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array.
But the output stil: Resource id #5

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$sql = "select bidang.idRel from relationship, bidang where relationship.idRel = bidang.idRel";
$result  =  mysql_query($sql);
echo  $result ;
?>
```

If i change it to 
    `echo  $result['idRel'] ;`
Nothing shown.
What should I do?
Please help me.

Comment: first, stop using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. second, you need to fetch rows to get those values. start using [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) today

Comment: here the $result is just a resource id, you need to actually fetch the data by mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array using this resource. Try: $mysql_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); var_dump($mysql_data);

Comment: I don't think you were using the API correctly if neither `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array` were not getting you want you wanted. The value "Resource id #5" is due to the result of `mysql_query` being a resource which is meant to be used as an argument to the other two functions I mentioned. While saying this, as @Ghost mentioned, `mysql_*` is deprecated. Look at the documentation for more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL query returning Resource id #5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142711/mysql-query-returning-resource-id-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are print a resource, not a result set.

Results are attached to it, but, its not an actual result set.

You need to fetch the result set by looping over the result set.

E.g.

```
$sql = "select bidang.idRel from relationship, bidang where relationship.idRel = bidang.idRel";
$result  =  mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print_r($row);
 }
}
```

**Note: Don't use mysql_ functions. They are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. Use mysqli_ instead.**

Comment: Use *mysqli_* or PDO instead?

Comment: I tried it says Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in XXX on line XXX

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
<?php
$sql = "select bidang.idRel from relationship, bidang where relationship.idRel = bidang.idRel";
$result  =  mysql_query($sql);
while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $raw['ColumnName'];
}
?>
```