# PHP and SQL count records

Tags: php, sql

I want show a number in the columns of mytable.

```
SELECT COUNT(0) FROM `db`.`tbl`;
```

and the result of the code:

> Resource id #5

this needs to print "2".

Here is my code:

```
        $icon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `**`.`**`;");
        // Here the problem!!
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `**`.`**`;");
        echo $count;

    if ($icon == 0) {
        $per = "URL";
        $title = "TITLE";
    }
    else if($icon =! 0)  {
        $per = "*****";
// Here the problem!!
        $title = "(".$count.") COUNT";
    }
    else {
        $per = "****";
        $title = "TITLE";
    }
        echo "
        <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='$per' />
        <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='$per' />
        <title>$title</title>
        ";
```

Comment: `COUNT(0)` what is 0 supposed to represent?

Comment: Show your code, what db extension are you using? It looks like you need to retrieve the data from the resultset?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I dont know what is the "0" but without number between brackets dont do nothing.

Comment: This isn't enough code. Which API are you using to connect with? Plus, you have answers given below.

Comment: `Resource id #5` => http://stackoverflow.com/a/19143351/ - so, show more/full code.

Comment: My code of connect and other code its ok, only my print count code its not good.

Comment: Well there you go. Look at the link I gave you above. THAT, is the reason why and THAT is why you need to show us your full code. As it stands, you are making everyone GUESS as to how you should be using proper syntax.

Comment: Are you looking for rows or columns?

Comment: Btw, `$icon =! 0` is invalid.

Comment: You're not fetching the result of the query. Something like `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` is going to be needed. For more info see the functions you are using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because poster seems to believe that providing enough information to actually answer their question is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the number of columns in a table, then you can use:

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'tbl' and table_schema = 'db';
```

Comment: wow, who dv this? Given what the OP included for code.

Comment: @SELECTanswerFROMme Show us your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . The original question is "I want show in number the columns of mytable".  Admittedly, the code has nothing to do with this, but the question was actually exceedingly clear -- although perhaps not what the OP intended.

Comment: I totally agree Gordon. I originally voted as unclear and haven't removed my vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compose your questions better in the future. It also seems like you are counting columns, not rows.

```
$icon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `**`.`**`;");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($icon);
$icon_result = $row['COLUMNAME'];
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as counter FROM `**`.`**`;");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);
$count_result = $row['counter'];
echo $count_result;
if ($icon == 0) {
    $per = "URL";
    $title = "TITLE";
} else if($icon != 0)  {
    $per = "*****";
    $title = "($count) COUNT";
} else {
    $per = "****";
    $title = "TITLE";
}
echo "<link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='$per' />
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='$per' />
<title>$title</title>";
```

Here's the functions doc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Director sees this: please delete the question

Comment: @SELECTanswerFROMme What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

The sql should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db`.`tbl`;
```

I presume you are getting the result in php for the recordset. you need to use function fetch_assoc() to get the record.

Comment: i tried it its same result

Comment: Can you share your php code?

Comment: That will count the rows, not the columns.

Comment: the sql query work in php my admin

Comment: and i cant user a function fetch_assoc i think that i can user mysql_assoc because my db is MYSQL

Comment: right, you can follow example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm